# Change Bundle-ID in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is there a way to change it in the current "version" of iTunes connect?

The field for me is right now "white" and not a textfield so there is no way for me?

there is no version uploaded yet or anything just metainformation inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change bundle id once it is created. Instead create new id.